# PHP CURL request to oauth2 password grant type for Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: types, oauth-2.0, request, passwords, sql-grant

Am trying to consume an API which needs Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded to issue a token. The following curl command works

```
curl -i \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -u SwVl97HRUgWHutJGzO1wt1JMjI5JVV62:SgnyQAA8ap0pPcFf \
  -d 'grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass' \
  https://api.test.com/identity/v1-sandbox/token
```

but when posting the request in PHP i.e.

```
$params = array(
  "client_id" => "SwVl97HRUgWHutJGzO1wt1JMjI5JVV62",
  "client_secret" => "SgnyQAA8ap0pPcFf",
  "username" => "user",
  "password" => "pass",
  "grant_type" => "password");

$curl = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, urlencode('user').':'.urlencode('pass'));

// Remove comment if you have a setup that causes ssl validation to fail
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$postData = "";

//This is needed to properly form post the credentials object
foreach($params as $k => $v)
{
   $postData .= $k . '='.urlencode($v).'&';
}

$postData = rtrim($postData, '&');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
echo "Performing Request...";

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
//print_r($json_response);

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
```

The API rejects my credentials. i.e.

```
 {
                    "code":"401.01.001",
                    "error":"unauthorized",
                    "message":"Unauthorized - Please check your credentials."
 }
```

When i check the curl request header, i found the content type changed to application/json yet i had requested it to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded i.e.

```
[url] => https://api.test.com/identity/v1-sandbox/token
[content_type] => application/json
[http_code] => 401
[header_size] => 166
[request_size] => 314
```

Has anyone encountered the above issue?

Comment: After some analysis, i have realized that the first one generates  `Authorization: Basic U3dWbDk3SFJVZ1dIdXRKR3pPMXd0MUpNakk1SlZWNjI6U2dueVFBQThhcDBwUGNGZg==`   while the second one generates  `Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz` thought both use base64 encoding... anyone with an idea please share...

Comment: never mind... was using curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, urlencode('user').':'.urlencode('pass')); instead of curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, urlencode('SwVl97HRUgWHutJGzO1wt1JMjI5JVV62').':'.urlencode('SgnyQAA8ap0pPcFf')); .... dummy mistake... guess am tired

Answer (score 0):

To set the header you have to use: CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

**Example:**

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```